# UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.Object[] com.secneo.sdk.Helper.makeInMemoryDexElements

Tags: java, android, android-library, dji-sdk

I am trying to [integrate the DJI SDK](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html) android mobile into my project by using [android-bridge-app](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Android-Bridge-App).
So I am running the bridgeApp inside the remote controller (which is connected with my laptop via USB cable) and I use an emulator for running DJI mobile SDK. The problem is that when I open the DJI mobile app, it crashes with `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Regarding the emulator, it runs on a system image of X86_64 (not the normal X86 image, as that one is not compatible with DJI SDK, so an arm device is needed)

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Error log:

```
V/sdk: DexInstall beging
    installSecondarDexs
W/e.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/BaseDexClassLoader;->pathList:Ldalvik/system/DexPathList; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
E/e.myapplicatio: No implementation found for java.lang.Object[] com.secneo.sdk.Helper.makeInMemoryDexElements(java.lang.Object, java.util.List, java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_secneo_sdk_Helper_makeInMemoryDexElements and Java_com_secneo_sdk_Helper_makeInMemoryDexElements__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_util_List_2Ljava_lang_String_2)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 12713
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.Object[] com.secneo.sdk.Helper.makeInMemoryDexElements(java.lang.Object, java.util.List, java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_secneo_sdk_Helper_makeInMemoryDexElements and Java_com_secneo_sdk_Helper_makeInMemoryDexElements__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_util_List_2Ljava_lang_String_2)
        at com.secneo.sdk.Helper.makeInMemoryDexElements(Native Method)
        at com.secneo.sdk.DexInstall.V26install(DexInstall.java:139)
        at com.secneo.sdk.DexInstall.installSecondaryDexes(DexInstall.java:71)
        at com.secneo.sdk.DexInstall.install(DexInstall.java:40)
        at com.secneo.sdk.Helper.install(Helper.java:43)
        at com.example.androiddrone.MApplication.attachBaseContext(MApplication.java:13)
        at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:351)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1159)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6683)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12713 SIG: 9
```

The error seems to happen on the DJI SDK side at `Helper.install(MApplication.this)`

```
package com.example.androiddrone;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

import com.secneo.sdk.Helper;

public class MApplication extends Application {

    private DemoApplication demoApplication;
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context paramContext) {
        super.attachBaseContext(paramContext);
        Helper.install(MApplication.this);
        if (demoApplication == null) {
            demoApplication = new DemoApplication();
            demoApplication.setContext(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        demoApplication.onCreate();
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.androiddrone;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import dji.common.error.DJIError;
import dji.common.error.DJISDKError;
import dji.sdk.base.BaseComponent;
import dji.sdk.base.BaseProduct;
import dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKInitEvent;
import dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    public static final String FLAG_CONNECTION_CHANGE = "dji_sdk_connection_change";
    private static BaseProduct mProduct;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private static final String IP = "192.168.42.8";

    private static final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSION_LIST = new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.VIBRATE,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
    };
    private List<String> missingPermission = new ArrayList<>();
    private AtomicBoolean isRegistrationInProgress = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 12345;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // When the compile and target version is higher than 22, please request the following permission at runtime to ensure the SDK works well.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkAndRequestPermissions();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initialize DJI SDK Manager
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    }

    /**
     * Checks if there is any missing permissions, and
     * requests runtime permission if needed.
     */
    private void checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        // Check for permissions
        for (String eachPermission : REQUIRED_PERMISSION_LIST) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, eachPermission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                missingPermission.add(eachPermission);
            }
        }
        // Request for missing permissions
        if (missingPermission.isEmpty()) {
            startSDKRegistration();
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            showToast("Need to grant the permissions!");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    missingPermission.toArray(new String[missingPermission.size()]),
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Result of runtime permission request
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        // Check for granted permission and remove from missing list
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            for (int i = grantResults.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    missingPermission.remove(permissions[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        // If there is enough permission, we will start the registration
        if (missingPermission.isEmpty()) {
            startSDKRegistration();
        } else {
            showToast("Missing permissions!!!");
        }
    }

    private void startSDKRegistration() {
        if (isRegistrationInProgress.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showToast("registering, pls wait...");

                    DJISDKManager.getInstance().registerApp(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), new DJISDKManager.SDKManagerCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRegister(DJIError djiError) {
                            if (djiError == DJISDKError.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS) {
                                showToast("Register Success");
                                DJISDKManager.getInstance().startConnectionToProduct();
                                DJISDKManager.getInstance().enableBridgeModeWithBridgeAppIP(IP);

                            } else {
                                showToast("Register sdk fails, please check the bundle id and network connection!");
                            }
                            Log.v(TAG, djiError.getDescription());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProductDisconnect() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onProductDisconnect");
                            showToast("Product Disconnected");
                            notifyStatusChange();

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onProductConnect(BaseProduct baseProduct) {
                            Log.d(TAG, String.format("onProductConnect newProduct:%s", baseProduct));
                            showToast("Product Connected");
                            notifyStatusChange();

                        }

                        public void onProductChanged(BaseProduct baseProduct) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComponentChange(BaseProduct.ComponentKey componentKey, BaseComponent oldComponent,
                                                      BaseComponent newComponent) {

                            if (newComponent != null) {
                                newComponent.setComponentListener(new BaseComponent.ComponentListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onConnectivityChange(boolean isConnected) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onComponentConnectivityChanged: " + isConnected);
                                        notifyStatusChange();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG,
                                    String.format("onComponentChange key:%s, oldComponent:%s, newComponent:%s",
                                            componentKey,
                                            oldComponent,
                                            newComponent));

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onInitProcess(DJISDKInitEvent djisdkInitEvent, int i) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDatabaseDownloadProgress(long l, long l1) {

                        }

                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void notifyStatusChange() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(updateRunnable);
        mHandler.postDelayed(updateRunnable, 500);
    }

    private Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FLAG_CONNECTION_CHANGE);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    };

    private void showToast(final String toastMsg) {

        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

DemoApplication:

```
package com.example.androiddrone;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import dji.common.error.DJIError;
import dji.common.error.DJISDKError;
import dji.common.useraccount.UserAccountState;
import dji.common.util.CommonCallbacks;
import dji.sdk.base.BaseComponent;
import dji.sdk.base.BaseProduct;
import dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKInitEvent;
import dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager;
import dji.sdk.useraccount.UserAccountManager;

public class DemoApplication extends Application {

    public static final String FLAG_CONNECTION_CHANGE = "uxsdk_demo_connection_change";

    private static BaseProduct mProduct;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private DJISDKManager.SDKManagerCallback mDJISDKManagerCallback;

    private Application instance;
    public void setContext(Application application) {
        instance = application;
    }

    @Override
    public Context getApplicationContext() {
        return instance;
    }

    public DemoApplication() {

    }

    /**
     * This function is used to get the instance of DJIBaseProduct.
     * If no product is connected, it returns null.
     */
    public static synchronized BaseProduct getProductInstance() {
        if (null == mProduct) {
            mProduct = DJISDKManager.getInstance().getProduct();
        }
        return mProduct;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        //Check the permissions before registering the application for android system 6.0 above.
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int permissionCheck2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M || (permissionCheck == 0 && permissionCheck2 == 0)) {

            //This is used to start SDK services and initiate SDK.
            DJISDKManager.getInstance().registerApp(getApplicationContext(), mDJISDKManagerCallback);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check if the permission is granted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        /**
         * When starting SDK services, an instance of interface DJISDKManager.DJISDKManagerCallback will be used to listen to
         * the SDK Registration result and the product changing.
         */
        mDJISDKManagerCallback = new DJISDKManager.SDKManagerCallback() {

            //Listens to the SDK registration result
            @Override
            public void onRegister(DJIError error) {
                if(error == DJISDKError.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS) {
                    DJISDKManager.getInstance().startConnectionToProduct();
                    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Register Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                    loginAccount();

                } else {
                    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Register Failed, check network is available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }
                Log.e("TAG", error.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onProductDisconnect() {
                Log.d("TAG", "onProductDisconnect");
                notifyStatusChange();
            }
            @Override
            public void onProductConnect(BaseProduct baseProduct) {
                Log.d("TAG", String.format("onProductConnect newProduct:%s", baseProduct));
                notifyStatusChange();
            }
            public void onProductChanged(BaseProduct baseProduct) {
                Log.d("TAG", String.format("onProductChanged newProduct:%s", baseProduct));
                notifyStatusChange();
            }
            @Override
            public void onComponentChange(BaseProduct.ComponentKey componentKey, BaseComponent oldComponent,
                                          BaseComponent newComponent) {
                if (newComponent != null) {
                    newComponent.setComponentListener(new BaseComponent.ComponentListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectivityChange(boolean isConnected) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "onComponentConnectivityChanged: " + isConnected);
                            notifyStatusChange();
                        }
                    });
                }

                Log.d("TAG",
                        String.format("onComponentChange key:%s, oldComponent:%s, newComponent:%s",
                                componentKey,
                                oldComponent,
                                newComponent));

            }
            @Override
            public void onInitProcess(DJISDKInitEvent djisdkInitEvent, int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDatabaseDownloadProgress(long l, long l1) {

            }

        };

    }

    private void loginAccount(){

        UserAccountManager.getInstance().logIntoDJIUserAccount(this,
                new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallbackWith<UserAccountState>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final UserAccountState userAccountState) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "Login Success");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(DJIError error) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "Login Error:" + error.getDescription());
                    }
                });
    }

    private void notifyStatusChange() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(updateRunnable);
        mHandler.postDelayed(updateRunnable, 500);
    }

    private Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FLAG_CONNECTION_CHANGE);
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    };

}
```

gradle(app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    packagingOptions{
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjivideo.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libSDKRelativeJNI.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFlyForbid.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libduml_vision_bokeh.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libyuv2.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libGroudStation.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFRCorkscrew.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libUpgradeVerify.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFR.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIFlySafeCore.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjifs_jni.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libsfjni.so"
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation ('com.dji:dji-uxsdk:4.11')
    compileOnly ('com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.11')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a lot. Start with the sdk example app on github and work your way from there.

I will be impressed if you manage to run the sdk from an emulator. You will be the first I know. It would be really nice if you can report back and tell how you managed to do that.

For example I can't see anything of:
apply from : "https://terra-1-g.djicdn.com/71a7d383e71a4fb8887a310eb746b47f/msdk/Android-CommonConfig/config_sample_all.gradle"

Which is kind of tricky, its include stuff at compiletime, you never know what you get.